# XML Query within Multiple Rows of Data

Tags: sql-server, xml

In my database table I have a XML column.

The value in the XML column is something like this:

**Row1**:

```
  <Data>
  <COLRowData>
  <DORowData>
  <PrimaryValue>Fever</PrimaryValue>  
  <EMRValue1> 101 <EMRValue1 />   
  <DataRowType>Past</DataRowType>
  <HasPositiveValue>True</HasPositiveValue>
  </DORowData>
  <DORowData>
  <PrimaryValue>Hypertension</PrimaryValue>
  <DataRowType>Present</DataRowType>
  <EMRValue1> No </EMRValue1>  
  <HasPositiveValue>False</HasPositiveValue>
 </DORowData>
 </COLRowData>
 </Data>
```

**Row2**:

```
 <Data>
 <COLRowData>
 <DORowData>
  <PrimaryValue>Diabetes</PrimaryValue>
  <DataRowType>Past</DataRowType>    
  <EMRValue1> No </EMRValue1>  
  <HasPositiveValue>True</HasPositiveValue>   
 </DORowData>
 <DORowData>
<PrimaryValue>Fever</PrimaryValue>
  <DataRowType>Present</DataRowType>
  <EMRValue1> 103  <EMRValue1 />
  <HasPositiveValue>True</HasPositiveValue>    
 </DORowData>    
 </COLRowData>
 </Data>
```

From this table I want to find all such rows where this following combination of Data exists in the single XML column:

- PrimaryValue: Fever
- DataRowType: Present

I am using this query:

```
Select * From TABLE 
WHERE  
   XML.exist('/Data/COLRowData/DORowData/DataRowType/text()[. = "Present"]') = 1 
   and
     XML.exist('/Data/COLRowData/DORowData/PrimaryValue/text()[. = "Fever"]') = 1
```

This query returns both the rows where as my requirement is that I should only find the Row2 as per the combination mentioned above.

Please help me with the query

Also how can i include the EMRValue1 - Value in Select statement from the XML satisfying the where clause?

Thanks i-one.
But since my where clause is satisfying data from this block only

```
   <DORowData>
    <PrimaryValue>Fever</PrimaryValue>
    <DataRowType>Present</DataRowType>
    <EMRValue1> 103  <EMRValue1 />
     <HasPositiveValue>True</HasPositiveValue>    
    </DORowData>
```

The EMRValue1 in the Select clause should only return 1 row with the EMRValue1 = 103

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should combine both conditions inside the same XPath:

```
select * from [TABLE]
where
    XML.exist('/Data/COLRowData/DORowData[DataRowType/text()[. = "Present"] and PrimaryValue/text()[. = "Fever"]]') = 1
```

To include `EMRValue1` in the select list:

```
select d.*, T.c.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(200)') EMRValue1
from [TABLE] d
    cross apply d.XML.nodes('/Data/COLRowData/DORowData/EMRValue1') T(c)
where d.XML.exist(...) = 1
```

note, that number of rows returned will inrease, because of multiple `EMRValue1` elements in `XML` data for each row

Comment: How can i include the "EMRValue1" in my Select statement from the XML Node which is satisfying the Where clause?

Comment: But since my where clause is satisfying data from this block only

     <DORowData>
     <PrimaryValue>Fever</PrimaryValue>
    <DataRowType>Present</DataRowType>
    <EMRValue1> 103  <EMRValue1 />
      <HasPositiveValue>True</HasPositiveValue>    
      </DORowData> 
The EMRValue1 in the Select clause should only return 1 row with the EMRValue1 = 103

Comment: In this case do following: `select d.XML, T.c.query('.') DORowDataXML, T.c.value('(EMRValue1/text())[1]', 'varchar(200)') EMRValue1 from [TABLE] d cross apply d.XML.nodes('/Data/COLRowData/DORowData') T(c) where T.c.exist('.[DataRowType/text()[. = "Present"] and PrimaryValue/text()[. = "Fever"]]') = 1`

Comment: This works just perfectly barring one issue. If the XML Block in which am querying has 3 diff Blocks of 'DORowData', then I am getting 3 rows as result with EMRValue1 from all 3, where as i would have just wanted one value i.e 103.

Comment: Do you mean, that you query data, where there are three blocks satisfying condition "Present" and "Fever" and you need only one of them?